# SmartEEPROM limitation to <= 1024Bytes at ATSAMD51J20A?

Tags: arm, microchip, eeprom

I use the SmartEeprom of an ATSAMD51J20A µC. The current and working configuration has a total EEPROMsize of 1024 bytes (fuses: `SEESBLK = 0x08` and `SEEPSZ = 0x01`). Now I need to increase the size up to 2048, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

If I set the fuses to `SEESBLK = 0x10` and `SEEPSZ = 0x01`, the appropriate GUI in my IDE (microchip studio) writes `0x00` into `SEEBLK`!

After some trial and error, it seems to me that the upper 4 bits of `SEESBLK` are ignored by the fuse-programing tool of microchip studio. For example, if I want to program `0x16` to `SEESBLK` (I know invalid configuration) a `0x06` is programed to the `SEEBLK` fuse. If I want to program `0x12`, it programs just `0x02`.

I didn't find any limitations in the data sheet, the corresponding tables theoretically provides configurations with significantly more EEPROMsize and the µC has 1MB flash available.

Does anyone have experience with this and uses the SmartEEEPROM with the mentioned  µC with a size of more than 1024 bytes?

Comment: When I look into the datasheet I think `SEESBLK`is only a 4 Bit value.